# Silverlight Validation Dependency Properties

Tags: validation, silverlight-3.0, dependency-properties

Anyone used SL3 validation when binding to dependency properties rather than notification properties?

If so, where did you write your setter validation code? Do you know of any good web examples?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is too late to answer this question, but it can help others, who was looking for answer and came to this link (As it happened with me).
There is another question as this one: [Validating input which is databound to a DependencyProperty - Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651728/validating-input-which-is-databound-to-a-dependencyproperty-silverlight). That one solved my problem.